# Dispatcher has no subscribers while trying to gracefully shutdown application

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following requirement for my application:

I have an integration flow which takes files from a directory via

```
Files.inboundAdapter
```

and a polling configuration as follows:

```
@Bean public PollerSpec orderOutboundFlowTempFileInPoller() {
    return Pollers
        .fixedDelay(pollerDelay)
        .maxMessagesPerPoll(100)
        .transactional();
```

}

The files should be transferred to a remote host via RemoteFileTemplate. The application runs in a docker container which should be stoppable for maintainance or rollout purposes. 
When the container is shutdown, the flow should finish writing the file to the remote host and should not accept new incoming files.
Therefore I have implemented a graceful shutdown as follows:

```
@Override public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextClosedEvent event) {
  LOG.info("Trying to gracefully shutdown App");
  //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
  allFlowPollers.forEach(
    p -> {
      try {
        p.destroy();
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("Unable to destroy poller.");
      }
    }
  );
  //CHECKSTLYE:ON
  FLOWS_TO_SHUTDOWN.forEach(GracefulShutdownAware::shutdown);
}
```

I assumed when I destroy the pollers, no further file would be read from source. The RemoteFileTemplate does send the current file correctly, there is no problem.
But the poller still seems to get new files and when the application is nearly shutdown, an exception appears as follows:

```
timestamp=15:55:56.599, thread=task-scheduler-2, severity=ERROR, class=o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler, message=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.flowTempFileIn.channel#0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, headers={file_originalFile=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, id=d04473ff-d1bd-173e-d801-b7b9fd31596c, file_name=1544088550162_57280.xml, file_relativePath=1544088550162_57280.xml, timestamp=1544108156591}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, headers={file_originalFile=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, id=d04473ff-d1bd-173e-d801-b7b9fd31596c, file_name=1544088550162_57280.xml, file_relativePath=1544088550162_57280.xml, timestamp=1544108156591}]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:290)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor292.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:385)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, headers={file_originalFile=/servicedata/tmp/1544088550162_57280.xml, id=d04473ff-d1bd-173e-d801-b7b9fd31596c, file_name=1544088550162_57280.xml, file_relativePath=1544088550162_57280.xml, timestamp=1544108156591}]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        ... 33 more
```

Is there any other way, I can achieve this requirement? Which is: stopping the application should let the current file finish, not accept further files to be read and still closing without any weird exceptions?

What I assume it's some kind of timing issue since the integration flow and the reaction to the ContextClosedEvent are running on different Threads. The poller isn't destroyed completely but the transform-subscriber of the outbound channel is already destroyed.

I also tried to stop the poller via control bus, but the outcome was the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about poller, but `InboundChannelAdapter`. Would be great to see your `IntegrationFlow` definition. Actually it must stop during application context shutdown. And you don't need to do anything else from your side.

The point is that all active Spring Integration components implement `SmartLifecycle` and they are `stop()`'ed gracefully during appropriate application context close phase.

Comment: I added the whole flow definition under:

https://pastebin.com/KDj8ubHE

As you can see, one flow is divided into smaller parts using multiple IntegrationFlows connected by DirectChannels.
The shutwown itself is as described above a ApplicationListener on ContextClosedEvent, which delegates the shutdown to a specific shutdown component per Flow. 
In the case of this specific OutboundFlow the shutdown is implemented as to wait for the current transfer to finish and block the messages pending in the current poll.

Comment: Everything in your code looks good. As I said: you don't need any custom destroy logic, if you just rely properly on the application context close. The `Files.inboundAdapter()` is going to be stopped first and only all other passive message handling components. Would be great to have some minimal Spring Boot project from you which reveal this problem. And, of course, without any Docker. That's confusing and doesn't look like related...